# Redux-Toolkit what are non-serializable values and why am i getting an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I´m setting up a redux store for my website.
It´s using a codemirror editor, who´s reference I want to have in store, so I can get or set it´s value without passing it around through all those components.
slice for the editor.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IUnControlledCodeMirror } from 'react-codemirror2-react-17';

interface AuditState {
  isLoading: boolean;
  loadingMessage: string;
  editorRef: null | IUnControlledCodeMirror;
}

const initialAuditState: AuditState = {
  isLoading: false,
  loadingMessage: '',
  editorRef: null
};

const auditSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'audit',
  initialState: initialAuditState,
  reducers: {
    changeLoading(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.isLoading = !state.isLoading;
      state.isLoading
        ? (state.loadingMessage = action.payload)
        : (state.loadingMessage = '');
    },
    setEditorRef(state, action: PayloadAction<IUnControlledCodeMirror>) {
      state.editorRef = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { changeLoading, setEditorRef } = auditSlice.actions;

export default auditSlice;
```

store configuration:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import auditSlice from './slices/auditSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    audit: auditSlice.reducer
  }
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

where I dispatch the editor to the redux store:

```
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/mode/solidity/solidity.js';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setEditorRef as setReduxEditor } from '../../../../Redux/slices/auditSlice';
import {
  IUnControlledCodeMirror,
  UnControlled as UnControlledEditor
} from 'react-codemirror2-react-17';

interface EditorProps {
  value: string;
}

const Editor = ({ value }: EditorProps) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onEditorDidMount = (editor: IUnControlledCodeMirror) => {
    dispatch(setReduxEditor(editor));
  };

  return (
    <div className="editor-container">
      <div className="editor-title text-center rounded-t-lg">
        SMART CONTRACT CODE
      </div>
      <UnControlledEditor
        editorDidMount={onEditorDidMount}
        value={value}
        className="code-mirror-wrapper"
        options={{
          lineWrapping: true,
          lint: true,
          mode: 'solidity',
          theme: 'material',
          lineNumbers: true
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

For some reason, I´m getting this error message:

> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path:
> `payload`. Value: CodeMirror {options: {…}, doc: Doc, display:
> Display, state: {…}, curOp: null, …}  Take a look at the logic that
> dispatched this action:  {type: 'audit/setEditorRef', payload:
> CodeMirror}

Any idea what this means and how to solve it?

Thankful for any help I can get!
Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Redux works better with `serializable objects`, such objects, are objects that can be easily converted into a storable format like `string`, `buffer` or `blob`. Sometimes objects are complex and they might have cyclic references inside, such logics can't be serialized with `JSON.stringify` for example, and that usually means that it's not a good idea to put such objects in a `Redux` store. It's not a `NO-NO` by the way, you still can do that by disabling the `serializable-check` middleware for certain reducers, payloads, as explained here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data
Just make sure you really need to save the instance of codeMirror in the Redux store (it means that you want listen to some changes), or if it's enough to store it in a `ref` instead.

Comment: Awesome, that was already really helpful! 
So how am I going to safe the codeeditor in a "ref"? 
You mean smth. like a useRef hook? and safe the useRef constant in the redux store?

Comment: That would still safe it in the store. Generllay, class instances should not go into the store, but only data. Otherwise you will get problems with addons like redux-persist or the devtools, as these expect to operate on data, not things with functionality. But generally: you can also just have your editor state as part of local component state. Putting all your state into global state is an antipattern from the start.

Comment: Yeah, that CodeMirror instance should _not_ go into the Redux store itself.  It's a UI layer thing only - keep it in a React `useRef` object and pass it down to other components via context.

Comment: Yes you can use a ref with `useRef` hook, and you can save in the redux store only a boolean state like `editorIsMounted:boolean` that you can toggle in the event listener `onEditorDidMount` as you were doing. When the Editor is mounted instead of saving the instance of codeMirror into the Redux store, you set it in a ref, and toggle the redux boolean value: `dispatch(setEditorIsMounted())`